# iMacros: How do you TAG an element that has no attributes

Tags: imacros

I have following HTML element in the document:

```
<select><option value="0">First</option></select>
```

The select element does not have any attributes. How do I tag it with iMacros?

I've tried

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT CONTENT=%0 (-910 wrong format)
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR= CONTENT=%0 (-910 wrong format)
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=% CONTENT=%0 (-910 wrong format)
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=*:* CONTENT=%0 (-910 wrong format)
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=* CONTENT=%0 (-910 can not parse macro line)
```

Extensive googling did not help.
This site: http://www.iopus.com/imacros/support/html2tag.htm says that ATTR=* could be used to ignore ATTR but it gave the runtime "can not parse" error.

How do I ignore ATTR in iMacros? Or is there another workaround?

EDIT: Apparently ATTR=* is correct. I think my file is just corrupted or something.

SOLUTION: I had extra "ATTR=*" line on the bottom of my file. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

use only this

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=*
```

i will work 
`CONTENT=%0` (-910 can not parse macro line) tagged in your code is the source of all errors so remove it

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the condition of the attribute.

An example follows:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=NAME:(write the select attribute name here) CONTENT=%0
```

Comment: It was about extra line in the bottom of my file. See Solution on original question.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a text inside (keyword) you can select based on that text.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=TXT:*keyword*
```